# How to pass multiples and selective Model into MVC razor Partial View?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

This is pretty basic but stumbling block on picking up MVC (coming from Web Forms of course)!

If a `_Layout.cshtml` has an optional sidebar as a Partial View, how do you get the Controller to pass the `ViewModel` to it (say, `BlogPosts`) without having to include it on all of the Controller's Page / View calls?

I appreciate the Controllers are where we need to construct Models (not inside Views, Partial or otherwise) and that any Partial View will inherit the Model from its parent (handy). But sometimes the parent page has its own `ViewModel` (eg. `SearchResults`) - and although I could turn it around by passing the sidebar `BlogPosts` into every View and only adding the the `SearchResults` for that page, am still stuck with same problem - how to selectively pass potential and multiple Models into parent and partial Views.

So we could put any additional Models in the `ViewBag` and then pull them out in any Partials, and this maybe the best solution, but seems messy (and not sure if they'd remain strongly typed). Or is the solution to use an additional Partial View Controller? In which case how you do it, because I get a null Object on the `foreach` in `_DefaultSideBar1.cshtml` and debug shows that the `additional _DefaultSideBar1()` is not running at all (so not surprising it's model doesn't get injected):

Current example route in `HomeController.cs`:

```
[HttpGet]
    public ActionResult SearchResults(string searchText)
    {
        ViewBag.Title = "Search Results";
        List<WebResult> searchData = new List<WebResult>();
        // generate searchData etc...
        return View(searchData);
    }
```

Current `SearchResults.cshtml` (which uses a `_Layout.cshtml`):

```
  @model IEnumerable<Bing.WebResult>
    // ... etc etc....
    @section DefaultSidebar1
    {
        @Html.Partial("_DefaultSidebar1")
    }
```

Anticipated additional current controller for sidebar which loads but not overridden in controller so with null Object Ref:

```
 [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult _DefaultSideBar1()
    {
        return View(db.BlogPosts.ToList());
    }
```

`Current _DefaultSideBar1.cshtml`:

```
  @model IEnumerable<Proj.MVC.SPQ.DataEntities.BlogPost>
    <ul>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <li>@Html.ActionLink(item.Title, "Details", new { id=item.ID })</li>
        }
    </ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This call

```
@Html.Partial("_DefaultSidebar1")
```

renders the view with the specified name and with no model (or rather with `null` for a model). That is why you get null reference. If you want to render it and have some model available, the correct way to call it is

```
@Html.Partial("_DefaultSidebar1", theModel)
```

Of course that assumes the model is available on the parent view, most likely as a part of parent view's model.

If you, on the other hand, would like to render part of a view a results of some action execution, you can use this:

```
@Html.RenderAction("_DefaultSidebar1", "ControllerName")
```

of course `ControllerName` is optional here. This will call your `_DefaultSidebar1` action, rather than just view, and render what result this action produces.

Comment: Thanks @Andrei,  almost there then, not `@Html.Partial("_DefaultSidebar1", theModel)` as the model may be completely different from the parent, so won't be inside the View. But great, `@Html.RenderAction("_DefaultSidebar1", "Home")` should do the trick – and fantastic, it does run that new controller code… but then it breaks the previously fine standard _Layout structure with `Section not defined: "DefaultHeader"`. Am fiddling (eg. substituting ~/Views/Shared/_DefaultHeader) but no joy yet, any ideas for final bit welcome (will go through @Roberts post just now but may be overkill for me)!

Comment: @Europhil, `theModel` can be any model, not necessary the one parent view is types with. However in practice it might be contained in the parent's view. As for your view error - that means that `_DefaultSidebar1` implicitly uses `_Layout` master, which it should not. have something like `@{ Layout = null; }` at the beginning of your partial view to turn this off

Comment: ah good point and that does indeed sort that view error! I did change it from code above to return a PartialView, and also had to use format `@{Html.RenderAction("_DefaultSidebar1");}` to compile in the SearchResults.cshtml. Now, I just have hopefully last error `The following sections have been defined but have not been rendered for the layout page "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml": "DefaultSidebar1".` This is presumably because we changed the `@Html.Partial("_DefaultSidebar1")` to your RenderAction, so am I missing something else?

Comment: @Europhil, maybe a weird question, but is this all your code? This error says that in your master view `_Layout` there is a section `DefaultSidebar1` which is not defined in your parent view. `RenderAction` on itself has nothing to do with that. However you might want to define this section in parent view and put call to `RenderAction` there

Comment: there is other extension method rendering code but shouldn't affect base issue - you've nudged my addled brain and I see now that i need to remove the `@section DefaultSidebar1` from all parent Views (including example SearchResults.cshtml above) as it's redundant thanks to your funkier `RenderAction` of a Partial View. It now all works perfectly! Many thanks for all this, marking as answer and have learnt a fair bit too, have a great weekend!

Answer (score 0):

Don't get stuck thinking your controller needs to be a work horse for everything.

Remember what we're doing here; building an HTML page.
A rendered HTML page can have multiple < form > elements.
With CSS, they can be all over the place...if you wanted that.

Each partial view can have it's own:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("action", "controller", new { routeValue = Model.Id }, FormMethod.Get|FormMethod.Post))
```

Therefor, separate the concerns of each area of your HTML page into different controllers that understand that data.

One might be:

```
public class ClientController : Controller
```

Another might be

```
public class AddressController : Controller
```

or even the very important...

```
public class WaffleController : Controller
```

You might want to have children, and I can't help you there, but your objects might want children, so you just pass that portion of the model to a partial view only concerned with that.

I have a page with partial views and view components that display multiple models in one HTML page. All are focused on the data they know and each are plug and play - they each load their own JS and asynchronously get the updates they need in response to user input, not affecting a whole page refresh.

Each view has it's own JS file for it's own work.

for example, my address controller always autofills the fields for the user to help them:

```
$(function() {

var urlGeoIeoip = "http://ip-api.com/json/?callback=?";

$.ajax({
    url: urlGeoIeoip,
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "json",
    timeout: 5000,
    success: function (geoipdata) {

        $("#Address_City").data("kendoComboBox").value(geoipdata.city);
        $("#Address_State").data("kendoComboBox").value(geoipdata.regionName);
        $("#Address_Country").data("kendoComboBox").value(geoipdata.country);

    }
}).fail(function(xhr, status) {
    if (status === "timeout") {
        // log timeout here
    }
});
});
```

But note that you can call your controller with the URL as well:

```
   url: 'Address/Validate',
```

And submit the form like this:

```
   data: $form.serialize()
```

And return json data to work with directly in JS by returning JsonResult:

```
public class AddressController : MyBaseController
{
    public JsonResult Validate(Address model)
    {
         //validate logic!      
         return Json(model, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
}
```

To do that, you'll need a helper for the JS bundle loader for a partial view:

```
public static class ScriptBundleManager
{

    private const string Key = "__ScriptBundleManager__";

    /// <summary>
    /// Call this method from your partials and register your script bundle.
    /// </summary>
    public static void Register(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string scriptBundleName)
    {
        //using a HashSet to avoid duplicate scripts.
        var set = htmlHelper.ViewContext.HttpContext.Items[Key] as HashSet<string>;
        if (set == null)
        {
            set = new HashSet<string>();
            htmlHelper.ViewContext.HttpContext.Items[Key] = set;
        }

        if (!set.Contains(scriptBundleName))
            set.Add(scriptBundleName);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// In the bottom of your HTML document, most likely in the Layout file call this method.
    /// </summary>
    public static IHtmlString RenderScripts(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper)
    {
        var set = htmlHelper.ViewContext.HttpContext.Items[Key] as HashSet<string>;

        return set != null ? Scripts.RenderFormat("<script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"{0}\"></script>", set.ToArray()) : MvcHtmlString.Empty;
    }


}
```

I have this in the App_Code directory

I call it like:

```
@Html.RenderScripts()
```

in my _Layout.cshtml

Comment: Thanks Robert, although as mentioned, I'm just picking up MVC and as there are enough issues to get head around, could do with saving the JSON complications til later! I already have multiple Controllers (another one for News editing etc) but this question and example should all be achievable using adjusted code provided and in one Controller, using standard _Layout structure. Hopefully your ideas are useful to someone or me in future, but not yet, cheers though!